# Why is a string key for a hash frozen?

Tags: ruby, string, hash, mutable

According to the [specification](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-store), strings that are used as a key to a hash are duplicated and frozen. Other mutable objects do not seem to have such special consideration. For example, with an array key, the following is possible.

```
a = [0]
h = {a => :a}
h.keys.first[0] = 1
h # => {[1] => :a}
h[[1]] # => nil
h.rehash
h[[1]] # => :a
```

On the other hand, a similar thing cannot be done with a string key.

```
s = "a"
h = {s => :s}
h.keys.first.upcase! # => RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

Why is string designed to be different from other mutable objects when it comes to a hash key? Is there any use case where this specification becomes useful? What other consequences does this specification have?

---

I actually have a use case where absence of such special specification about strings may be useful. That is, I read with the `yaml` gem a manually written YAML file that describes a hash. the keys may be strings, and I would like to allow case insensitivity in the original YAML file. When I read a file, I might get a hash like this:

```
h = {"foo" => :foo, "Bar" => :bar, "BAZ" => :baz}
```

And I want to normalize the keys to lower case to get this:

```
h = {"foo" => :foo, "bar" => :bar, "baz" => :baz}
```

by doing something like this:

```
h.keys.each(&:downcase!)
```

but that returns an error for the reason explained above.

Comment: Looks like, for my purpose, the best I can do is `h.keys.each{|s| h.store(s.downcase, h.delete(s))}`.

Comment: I can only guess at "why". As well as strings being a more common use case than arrays, I suspect freezing a string would be easier to implement. If I knew Perl, I'd look at whether Ruby is trying to be consistent with Perl in its hash behavior. If I was proficient in Japanese, I'd look at when the freezing of keys were implemented, and see if that was the result of a bug report or discussion on a mailing list (presumably in Japanese for something so early in Ruby's history).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm [Here](http://doc.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.9.2/class/Hash.html) it says arrays and hashes do not make good keys for a hash because they can be modified, and strings are frozen so that you don't have to call rehash. Consistent with steenslag's answer.

Comment: not sure when this method was added, with [transform_keys!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21) you can do `h.transform_keys!(&:downcase)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In short it's just Ruby trying to be nice.

When a key is entered in a Hash, a special number is calculated, using the `hash` method of the key. The Hash object uses this number to retrieve the key. For instance, if you ask what the value of `h['a']` is, the Hash calls the `hash` method of string 'a' and checks if it has a value stored for that number. The problem arises when someone (you) mutates the string object, so the string 'a' is now something else, let's say 'aa'. The Hash would not find a hash number for 'aa'.

The most common types of keys for hashes are strings, symbols and integers. Symbols and integers are immutable, but strings are not. Ruby tries to protect you from the confusing behaviour described above by dupping and freezing string keys. I guess it's not done for other types because there could be nasty performance side effects (think of large arrays).

Comment: Thanks for answering the theoretical part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

See [this thread on the ruby-core mailing list](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1192230) for an explanation (freakily, it happened to be the first mail I stumbled across when I opened up the mailing list in my mail app!).

<s>I've no idea about the first part of your question, but h</s>Here is a practical answer for the 2nd part:

```
  new_hash = {}
  h.each_pair do |k,v|
   new_hash.merge!({k.downcase => v}) 
  end

  h.replace new_hash
```

There's lots of permutations of this kind of code,

```
  Hash[ h.map{|k,v| [k.downcase, v] } ]
```

being another (and you're probably aware of these, but sometimes it's best to take the practical route:)

Answer (score 4):

Immutable keys make sense in general because their hash codes will be stable.

This is why strings are specially-converted, in this part of MRI code:

```
if (RHASH(hash)->ntbl->type == &identhash || rb_obj_class(key) != rb_cString) {
  st_insert(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, val);
}
else {
  st_insert2(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, val, copy_str_key);
}
```

In a nutshell, in the string-key case, `st_insert2` is passed a pointer to a function that will trigger the dup and freeze.

So if we theoretically wanted to support immutable lists and immutable hashes as hash keys, then we could modify that code to something like this:

```
VALUE key_klass;
key_klass = rb_obj_class(key);
if (key_klass == rb_cArray || key_klass == rb_cHash) {
  st_insert2(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, val, freeze_obj);
}
else if (key_klass == rb_cString) {
  st_insert2(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, val, copy_str_key);
}
else {
  st_insert(RHASH(hash)->ntbl, key, val);
}
```

Where `freeze_obj` would be defined as:

```
static st_data_t
freeze_obj(st_data_t obj)
{
    return (st_data_t)rb_obj_freeze((VALUE) obj);
}
```

So that would solve the specific inconsistency that you observed, where the array-key was mutable. However to be really consistent, more types of objects would need to be made immutable as well.

Not *all* types, however. For example, there'd be no point to freezing immediate objects like Fixnum because there is effectively only one instance of Fixnum corresponding to each integer value. This is why only `String` needs to be special-cased this way, not `Fixnum` and `Symbol`.

Strings are a special exception simply as a matter of convenience for Ruby programmers, because strings are very often used as hash keys.

Conversely, the reason that other object types are *not* frozen like this, which admittedly leads to inconsistent behavior, is mostly a matter of convenience for Matz & Company to not support edge cases.  In practice, comparatively few people will use a container object like an array or a hash as a hash key.  So if you do so, it's up to you to freeze before insertion.

Note that this is not strictly about performance, because the act of freezing a non-immediate object simply involves flipping the `FL_FREEZE` bit on the `basic.flags` bitfield that's present on every object.  That's of course a cheap operation.

Also speaking of performance, note that if you are going to use string keys, and you are in a performance-critical section of code, you might want to freeze your strings before doing the insertion.  If you don't, then a dup is triggered, which is a more-expensive operation.

**Update** @sawa pointed out that leaving your array-key simply frozen means the original array might be unexpectedly immutable outside of the key-use context, which could also be an unpleasant surprise (although otoh it would serve you right for using an array as a hash-key, really). If you therefore surmise that dup + freeze is the way out of that, then you would in fact incur possible noticeable performance cost. On the third hand, leave it unfrozen altogether, and you get the OP's original weirdness. Weirdness all around. Another reason for Matz et al to defer these edge cases to the programmer.

Comment: Freezing the original key without duplicating it would be confusing. Duplicating would be a must if a key is going to be frozen automatically. Even if freezing is cheap, duplicating an array, etc. is expensive, and so it seems to be a performance issue after all. Your last paragraph is informative. Are you sure that, if a string is frozen from the beginning, it would not be duplicated when used as a hash key?

Comment: As for being sure whether that's how it works, yes you can see it here: `if (OBJ_FROZEN(orig)) return orig;` at the top of `rb_str_new_frozen()`, currently located here: github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L673

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that "duplicating would be a must"... if the consistent behavior for setting hash keys was that they all got simply frozen, then people who did unusual things like try to use an array as a key and then mutate it later would quickly discover that that usage doesn't work, when the update attempt failed loudly. The consistency would probably be helpful sometimes. Now, I definitely see where you're coming from too... Just seems arguable what to optimize for -- consistency, performance, protecting programmers from the consequences of doing odd things, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are askin 2 different questions: theoretical and practical. Lain was the first to answer, but I would like to provide what I consider a proper, lazier solution to your practical question:

```
Hash.new { |hsh, key| # this block get's called only if a key is absent
  downcased = key.to_s.downcase
  unless downcased == key # if downcasing makes a difference
    hsh[key] = hsh[downcased] if hsh.has_key? downcased # define a new hash pair
  end # (otherways just return nil)
}
```

The block used with `Hash.new` constructor is only invoked for those missing keys, that are actually requested. The above solution also accepts symbols.

Answer (score 0):

A very old question - but if anyone else is trying to answer the "how can I get around the hash keys are freezing strings" part of the question...

A simple trick you could do to solve the String special case is:

```
class MutableString < String
end

s = MutableString.new("a")
h = {s => :s}
h.keys.first.upcase! # => RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
puts h.inspect
```

Doesn't work unless you are creating the keys, and unless you are then careful that it doesn't cause any problems with anything that strictly requires that the class is exactly "String"